# Equivalence Relation of $(x\land y)\lor ( \lnot x \land \lnot y)=1$

Tags: boolean-algebra

Define $ R \subseteq T xT $ as follows:

> $ (x,y) \in R \iff (x\land y)\lor ( \lnot x\land \lnot y)=1$.

Show, using the laws of Boolean Algebra, that R is an equivalence relation.
Hint: if $ A = B = 1 \;then\; A \land B \land C = A \land B \implies C = 1$

I am assuming that I just need to prove that 
$(x\land y)\lor ( \lnot x\land \lnot y)=1$

So, what I have did so far,

1. $(x\land y)\lor ( \lnot x\land \lnot y) $
2. $(x \lor ( \lnot x\land \lnot y)) \land ( y \lor ( \lnot x\land \lnot y)) $
3. $ (( x \lor \lnot x) \land ( x \lor \lnot y)) \land ((y \lor \lnot x) \land ( y \lor \lnot y)) $
4. $(1 \land (x \lor \lnot y)) \land ((y \lor \lnot x) \land 1)$
5. $(x \lor \lnot y) \land (y \lor \lnot x)$

feel like I am chasing my tail here.

I have go about the question in the wrong direction, I should have prove it to be equivalence relation, which i already know how. My mistake for not writing the full question at first. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I see someone did the edit from (x /\ y)' to above x' /\ y', but is that true? I thought that it might be (x /\ y)' = x' \/ y'

Comment: aha, if it were $\lnot(x\land y)$ then it would be 1.

Comment: @Isabella can you explain to me? and I am looking for guide to write the formula down in here, once I understand I will edit my post and write what I have done so far.

Comment: You originally wrote $(x\land y)\lor\lnot(x\lor y)$ but this is not 1 or true (you can verify giving values of $0$ and $1$ to the variables)

Comment: Given any simple Boolean expression, my first instinct would be to go for a truth table.

Comment: @ Sabyasachi, I see, but I need to prove it using boolean algebra law

Comment: @JacobManaker's answer shows that this is false. Are you sure you haven't mis-transcribed the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You do *not* need to prove that $(x\wedge y)\vee(\neg x\wedge\neg y)=1$ (in fact, the latter is false: in general take $x=0$ and $y=1$).

You need to show three things:

1. For all $x$, you have $x~R~x$.
2. For all $x$ and $y$ such that $x~R~y$, you have $y~R~x$.
3. For all $x$, $y$, and $z$ such that $x~R~y$ and $y~R~z$, you have $x~R~z$.

Substituting the definition of $R$, you need to show

1. For all $x$, you have $(x\wedge x)\vee(\neg x\wedge\neg x)=1$.
2. For all $x$ and $y$, if $(x\wedge y)\vee(\neg x\wedge\neg y)=1$, then $(y\wedge x)\vee(\neg y\wedge\neg x)=1$.
3. For all $x$, $y$, and $z$, if $(x\wedge y)\vee(\neg x\wedge\neg y)=1$ and $(y\wedge z)\vee(\neg y\wedge\neg z)=1$, then $(x\wedge z)\vee(\neg x\wedge\neg z)=1$.

The first is just idempotency of boolean operations, the second symmetry.  The third requires you to "or" the givens together and apply distributivity.  I'll leave the details to you.

Comment: can we let x = 1, y = 1?

Comment: @dst: counterexamples don’t work like that. Read Alex.Jordan’s comment: have you mistakenly made a typo?

Comment: @ Clayton, I checked my question again and they are correct. the question is asking to prove that it is true.

Comment: @ Clayton, So I have misunderstood the question, apparently I am suppose to show that its a equivalence relation, ie. reflexive, symmetrical, transitive.